# Traverse circular linked list in java

Tags: java, linked-list, circular-list

For the show() method, I'm supposed to traverse each **Node** in the circular linked list, starting at **first**, and printing each **Point** using StdOut.println().

I am able to traverse and print out each Node in the circular linked list without repeating. I just feel like there's a better way to write this, but I can't figure out how to include the first Node in the while loop. If I get rid of the line above the while loop, then the last node doesn't get printed out. Putting it above the while loop does. Is there a way to write it and have the last Node included without writing the line above the while loop?

```
public class Tour {
// Nested class Node to contain a Point and a reference
// to the next Node in the tour
private class Node {
    Point p;
    Node next;
}

private Node first;
//private Node last;
private int size;
private double distance;

// Create an empty Tour
// Constructor that creates an empty tour
public Tour()
{
    first = null;
    //last = null;
    size = 0;
    distance = 0.0;
}

// Create a 4 point tour a->b->c->d->a
// Constructor that creates a 4 point tour and is
// intended to assist with debugging
public Tour(Point a, Point b, Point c, Point d)
{   
    Node one = new Node();
    Node two = new Node();
    Node three = new Node();
    Node four = new Node();

    one.p = a;
    two.p = b;
    three.p = c;
    four.p = d;

    one.next = two;
    two.next = three;
    three.next = four;
    four.next = one;

    first = one;
    //last = four;
}

// Print the tour to standard output
// Print constituent points to standard output
public void show()
{
    Node tmp = first;

    if (tmp == null)
    {
        StdOut.println("");
        return;
    }

    StdOut.println(tmp.p.toString());
    while (tmp.next != first)
    {
        tmp = tmp.next;
        StdOut.println(tmp.p.toString());
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a do-while loop to get rid of the line just before the while loop:

```
Node tmp = first;

if (tmp == null)
{
    StdOut.println("");
    return;
}

do
{
    StdOut.println(tmp.p.toString());
    tmp = tmp.next;
} while (tmp != first);
```

There's not much else you can do to improve the method.

Comment: Actually, that should be `while (tmp != first)`

Answer (score 0):

change it to a do-while loop.  you'll just have to include an if test inside to prevent a NullPointerException for the case where the CLL is empty (aka the primary node is null).